# change the parameters on httpd.conf file by using docker

Tags: python, django, docker

I use docker. I try to change the parameter Timeout on httpd.conf file:

```
TypesConfig '/etc/mime.types'


<IfVersion < 2.4>
DefaultType text/plain
</IfVersion>

TypesConfig '/etc/mime.types'

HostnameLookups Off
MaxMemFree 64
Timeout 60
ListenBacklog 500

<IfDefine MOD_WSGI_WITH_HTTP2>
Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
</IfDefine>

<IfVersion >= 2.2.15>
RequestReadTimeout header=15-30,MinRate=500 body=15,MinRate=500
</IfVersion>

LimitRequestBody 1073741824
```

The problem is that it need restart the docker for save the changes by the `docker down` and `docker-compose up -d` commands and the file is recreated.

How can I change the Timeout parameter before the upload docker?

Comment: I would suggest to have the file on the host machine and put it into the corresponding image using a volume.

Comment: @JordanSimba, Can you explain?

Comment: Docker volumes allow you to put files that exist on your host machine (the computer running docker) and put them into a container at runtime (docker-compose up -d). So on your local filesystem you can edit the file, and in docker container, the change will also appear. Whatever state the file is in on your filesystem, it will be the same in the docker container @MEDZ shows the syntax

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the value from the docker instance. Try to recreate the file inside your project and then refer to it using a volume:

```
version: "3"
services:
  #assuming the following service is the one that has the conf file
  app:
    volumes:
      - /path/inside/instance/to/httpd.conf:./path/in/app/folder/to/httpd.conf
    #other settings ...
```

Then you can make any edits to this file and it will overwrite the other file. Do not forget to restart docker after that.